# (REOPENED) Reopen "boss keeps changing his mind"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

See question: [My boss keeps changing the requirements. How can I get him to make up his mind?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/89310/3192)

I have edited the question to make it sound like less of a rant, and focus more on the issue. Please consider reopening it, or discuss if/how the question can be further improved.

Note: I have also [edited my answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/89312/revisions) to the question to focus on solution to the issue, and removed the admonishing tone.

Comment: This question has an accepted answer. You shouldn't put a "reopened" meta-tag in the title.

Comment: @grgarside Why not?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116104/222623

Comment: @grgarside Here: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4423/3192 This is not StackOverflow, leave us alone.

Comment: Those StackOverflow guys have this habit of making arbitrary rules without giving any reason (other than don't do this, it is wrong). If it isn't broken, don't fix it. What exactly is the *problem* you are trying to solve here? Our own moderators have recommended to use one of these two approaches. You have to give us a more convincing reason than sharing some link from other site for why doing *both* should not be allowed. Anyway, this is meta, not the main site.

Comment: @MaskedMan Uh, you realize that the two posts are about different things, right? One is about not putting "SOLVED" in the title -- which, incidentally, is on the network-wide meta, and as such applies to _every_ site, not Stack Overflow -- the other is about custom-flagging for mods so they can apply a special mod-only tag. grgarside was talking about not adding this question's equivalent of [SOLVED]; you're replying by saying "but the mods said don't custom-flag!" The two are unconnected. Removed [SOLVED] and let the accepted answer say it for you.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Have you actually bothered reading the moderator's post? She clearly suggests editing the question title as an alternative to the tag request. Anyway that [SOLVED] or whatever is not relevant here. Meta works differently. Besides each site can make its own rules. So please try to spend some time on *this* site before you can decide what should and should not be done here.

Comment: @MaskedMan Did _you_ even bother reading it? Right before that sentence, there's this one, which I'll quote to make sure you see it: "Ideally, report the results in an answer and then accept it; an accepted answer is the usual signal for "no more help needed"". That _very heavily_ implies that the "edit the title" solution is for cases where there _is_ no accepted answer, which there is in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I voted to reopen.  This is such a common problem in the workplace that I can not possibly see how this could be off topic.